# SuperNotCalledException running unit test

Tags: android

I am trying to run this Android unit test, following this tutorial ::

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html

and in doing so get a **SuperNotCalledException**

**Here's the test class code ::**

```
package com.example.helloandroid2.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.helloandroid2.HelloAndroid2Activity;

public class HelloAndroid2Test extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<HelloAndroid2Activity>
{
    private HelloAndroid2Activity mActivity;
    private TextView mView;
    private String resourceString;

    public HelloAndroid2Test()
    {
        super("com.example.helloandroid2", HelloAndroid2Activity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        super.setUp();
        mActivity = this.getActivity();
        mView = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(com.example.helloandroid2.R.id.textview);
        resourceString = mActivity.getString(com.example.helloandroid2.R.string.hello);
    }

    public void testPreconditions()
    {
          assertNotNull(mView);
    }

    public void testText()
    {
          assertEquals(resourceString,(String)mView.getText());
    }
}
```

**The class I'm actually testing ::**

```
package com.example.helloandroid2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid2Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
}
```

**I've set the project API levels at 2_3_1 and am using an avd set at the same.
Am running Eclipse with ADT on Windows Vista.**

All wisdom greatfully recieved. Thanks in advance.

Chris

Answer (score 4):

Your `onCreate()` method in `HelloAndroid2Activity` needs to call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Answer (score 2):

```
public class HelloAndroid2Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
}
```